# Pass string value to bit data type work properly in Win XP but not in Win Server 2003

Tags: postgresql

I have created function pgsql:

**Function Name**: `fn_add_xyz(integer,bit,boolean,text)`.

When we call above function

**Call Function**: `select * from fn_add_xyz(1,'1','true','hello');`

through java application in window XP .it works properly.

But when we call above function through same Java application in Win server 2003. It gives error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function fn_add_xyz(integer,character varying,character varying,text)does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This problem occur in client environment. We have tested this in our environment, it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined as fn_add_xyz(integer, bit, boolean, text), while you are trying to call fn_add_xyz(integer, text, text, text).

Try putting explicit casts that match your function's signature and/or remove the quotes around the boolean value:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_add_xyz(1, '1'::bit, true, 'hello');
```